# System freezes with every distro I try

Tags: freeze

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad 11e with the Celeron N2940 CPU and upgraded to 8GB of memory. I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 (first time Linux) and found my system didn't run so well. So I tried Xubuntu, and then Lubuntu, and they all gave me problems (freezing). So I installed Linux Mint and again I experienced the freezing.

This happens randomly, there is no specific culprit to cause it to freeze. It has happened during videos, web browsing, typing, etc. Also, I do not think it is faulty RAM because the system runs Windows 10 perfectly fine. And with many more resources in use as well.

Comment: Can you run memtest86 from a Linux live cd, and let that run for a few hours ?

Comment: Your processor is affected by the c-state bug

Comment: @Zanna C-state bug, got it. 

Do you recommend a distro that does not suffer from this?

Comment: it's a kernel bug, so there's no way to escape it by distro-hopping, we're stuck with it until the kernel gets patched once and for all. See the linked post for highly effective workaround :)

Comment: I'll try the workaround. So are you implying this bug affects every Linux distribution? I am still trying to wrap my head around what exactly a kernel is. Does every Linux distribution use the same kernel? Again I don't have this problem at all with Windows 10, which leads to my question about every Linux distribution suffering from this and wondering if all Linux distributions use the same kernel (if I'm beginning to understand the kernel).

Comment: As I understand it, the developers of each distro patch the kernel. All flavors of Ubuntu use the Ubuntu kernel, but, of course, newer versions use later kernels. I am not aware of any current distro that has fully solved this issue, but I know that Torvalds himself is aware of the bug, and wrote a patch for it in earlier kernels - hopefully it will get fixed upstream eventually. I have the Asus X205TA and one hacker with the same device wrote a patch to use C7 & thus save battery, but I prefer using Ubuntu kernel + workaround to compiling the vanilla kernel as it makes little difference